# Visual Studio Plugin/Shortcut for Eclipse-like exception handler templates?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, plugins, exception, keyboard-shortcuts

Maybe somebody help me with this. Assume we have to following line of code:

```
File.Delete("C:\\test.txt");
```

Most (not all) .NET developers will write a generic exception handler like this:

```
try
{
File.Delete("C:\\test.txt");
}
catch ( Exception e ) { //... }
```

...instead of the detailed version handling all exceptions listed in the documentation ([MSDN - File.Delete Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)):

```
try
{
File.Delete("C:\\test.txt");
}
catch ( ArgumentException arge ) { //... }
catch ( ArgumentNullException argne ) { //... }
catch ( DirectoryNotFoundException dnfe ) { //... }
catch ( IOException ioe ) { //... }
catch ( NotSupportedException nse ) { //... }
catch ( PathTooLongException ptle ) { //... }
catch ( UnauthorizedAccessException ptle ) { //... }
```

Why are so many .NET developers are writing generic exception handlers? The answer is because they are tired of looking up each exception in the API documentation (if there is a documentation at all).

Now to my question: Is there a Visual Studio plugin or unknown shortcut, which can do this for me? The Eclipse Java IDE has a buildin shortcut which exactly does this this automatically for the methods within the try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any such plugin existing for VS. Yes this is definitely a great feature to have and improves the coding experience. i would suggest you to submit your feedback in http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio and based on the votes we get for this feature request, the Visual Studio Team can plan it for their future releases.